Number of equivalence classes from an equivalence relation defined by a matrix
Say you’ve got an equivalence relation $\sim$ defined by a matrix A such that $a_{ij}=\mathbf{1}_{\{i\sim j\} }$. Is there a way to figure out the number of equivalence classes?
Assume the matrix is too big to find the number of equivalence classes by hand. Thanks!

What does $\mathbb 1_{{i-j}}$ mean?  In any case, you should edit to include your efforts.  Presumably, whatever you are asking is easy if the  number of elements is small.   Working out some small examples explicitly would be a good start (and would clarify your notation).

Do you perhaps mean that $A$ is a $0$-$1$ matrix and $\sim$ is defined so that $i \sim j = [a_{i,j} = 1]$, where the brackets indicate the Iverson bracket notation?

See an interesting remark in the answer here showing that your issue is equivalent to find a re-numbering of the nodes giving a block diagonal matrix equivalent to the initial one.

@PaulTanenbaum yes I mean that the $a_{ij}$ is 1 if $i\sim j$ and 0 otherwise

Usually that would be stated the other way round. Because you wrote that $\sim$ is defined by $A$, one would expect to see $i \sim j$ expressed in terns of $a_{i,j}$, not $a_{i,j}$ in terms of $i \sim j$.

Ah, l just stumbled across the notation ${\textbf 1}_S$ for the indicator function of a set $S$. But of course, $i \sim j$ isn’t a set.

Well...there's depth-first or breadth-first search. Your matrix implicitly defines a graph on the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. Pick a node of this graph and traverse all edges leaving it and mark them; repeat, ignoring any marked nodes you encounter. When you're done, you've got an equivalence class. Move to an unmarked node and repeat.
In matrix terms, this amounts to the following, although I've applied a bunch of simplifications along the way.

Let $S$ be a bit-vector of $n$ zeros. Treat each row of the matrix as a bit-vector as well. We'll call $S$ the "marked items".
Let $G = S$
let $k = 1$

Repeat:

If $S$ has no zeroes, we're done. $k$ is the number of equivalence classes

Otherwise:

Increment $k$
Pick the first $i$ with $S(i) = 0$ (the first "unmarked" item).
$S = S \vee A_i$, i.e., "mark" all nodes equivalent to $i$.
Go back to the repeat



That's it. Because row 1 tells you everything that's in the same class as index 1; if those indices are 1, 2, 3, and 7 (out of 8), then we mark those look at row $4$ (because 4 is the next unmarked index). If row4 is nonzero at locations $4, 5, 6$ and $8$, then we mark those. And then we look at row $7$, which is only nonzero in location 7, and we mark that. That gives 3 equivalence classes.
This can be done in time proportional to $n^2$ if you actually do the "or" stuff for each round. If you use a hashtable (or even a linear array) to "mark" vertices, it takes time $nk$, where $n$ is the size of the matrix $A$ and $k$ is the number of equivalence classes, because for each class, you have to walk through all the entries of some row (i.e., do $n$ units of work) and enter them in the hashtable/array.
Note that if $A$ is a pre-equivalence relation rather than an equivalence relation, i.e., $A$ describes an $n$-node graph with $a_{ij}$ indicating an edge between nodes $i$ and $j$, then you're searching for connected components of the graph, and it takes more work. The key thing with your matrix is that if $i$ and $j$ are equivalent, then row $i$ and row $j$ of your graph are identical.
If you just want to use off-the-shelf stuff, you could sort $A$ by rows (at a cost of $n \log n$ row comparisons, each of which takes time proportional to $n$, so a cost of $n^2 \log n$, and then remove duplicates, which is another $n$ operations. (Try to figure out why you don't have to look at all entries in a row to determine whether rows in the sorted array are equal.)

So how do you interpret “ $a_{ij}=\mathbf{1}_{{i\sim j} }$”?

Great answer, thanks!

It took me a while to guess that it meant "the ij entry is 1 if i and j are in the same class" (and 0 otherwise).
